# ¿Cómo girar un planeta (3D) en QML?

Tags: qt, 3d, qml

Estoy trabajando con el ejemplo de "[Qt 3D: Planets QML Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-planets-qml-example.html#qt-3d-implementation)".
Lo que quiero es **rotar un planeta** por medio de un *Slider*.
Ya se que viene uno similar pero es para el cambio de velocidad de rotación, pero quiero que a través del Slider se pueda girar el planeta según los grados que sean necesarios de acuerdo al cambio que se hace en el Slider.
Igual si saben de una técnica que sea mejor que el Slider la acepto con todo gusto.
Espero me puedan ayudar.
[image: Ésta es la imagen de mi planeta]
Este es un fragmento de mi código:

```
StyledSlider {  //Deslizante que ocuparé para rotar mi planeta
    id: speedSlider
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    width: sliderLength
    value: /* Valor según mi función */
    minimumValue: /* Valor según mi función */
    maximumValue: /* Valor según mi función */
    onValueChanged: /* aquí iría la función para rotar mi planeta */
}
Text {
    anchors.right: speedSlider.left
    anchors.verticalCenter: speedSlider.verticalCenter
    anchors.rightMargin: 10
    font.family: "Helvetica"
    font.pixelSize: textSize
    font.weight: Font.Light
    color: "white"
    text: "Rotation"
}
```

Comment: Hola Brand, por favor agrega un __[mcve]__ que muestre lo que tu estás haciendo. En el enlace que compartes funciona, por lo que no hay ningún problema que resolver. Si buscas ideas, sugerencias, recomendaciones u opiniones es mejor que uses Google porque ese tipo de preguntas no se permiten en [es.so].